# iOS NSDateFormatter formats incorrectly when Calendar is Japanese or Buddhist

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

I'm seeing a problem with NSDateFormatter on iOS when Settings/General/International/Calendar is set to either Japanese or Buddhist on both the simulator and a real device.  It doesn’t seem to matter what the Language is set to, and the Region Format only re-arranges things (but it is still bad).  The results below are all for when 'Language' = English and 'Region Format' = Japan.

Here's my code (ARC is enabled):

```
// Configure the Date Formatter
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];

// Format the date string
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

And the results:

- iOS 4.3 (Calendar = Japanese), dateString =  “平成24/04/13”
- iOS 5.1 (Calendar = Japanese), dateString = “H.24/04/09”
- iOS 4.3 (Calendar = Buddhist), dateString =  “BE2555/04/13”
- iOS 5.1 (Calendar = Buddhist), dateString = “BE2555/04/13”

I found this link:  http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/12/ios-5-breaking-nsdateformatter/, which is interesting but doesn’t really point me to a solution.  I also found this: [NSDateFormatter and Japanese calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677006/nsdateformatter-and-japanese-calendar), so I changed my code slightly:

```
[dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:[[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0]]];
```

Then my results are this (these all seem wrong to me, that’s essentially US MM/DD/YY format):

- iOS 4.3 (Calendar = Japanese), dateString = “4/13/12”
- iOS 5.1 (Calendar = Japanese), dateString = “4/13/12”
- iOS 4.3 (Calendar = Buddhist), dateString = “4/13/12”
- iOS 5.1 (Calendar = Buddhist), dateString = “4/13/12”

Of all of the results above, the only one that looks correct to me is iOS4.3 with Calendar = Japanese.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

The region is what effects the date format, not the language. You're setting the format to use the user's region:

`[dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];`

If you want a consistent format across all users you can set it to the system's local:

`[dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]];`

Comment: up voted just because you took the time to answer an un-answered oldie!